# Apps script on eclipse : Error reading contents of project from Drive;

Tags: eclipse, google-apps-script

[image]

I'm trying to use the google apps script plugin for eclipse (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script) When I follow the directions and try to import an apps script project, The import wizard does not appear to populate, and I end up with the error in the title . The logs have the following:

```
  !SESSION 2017-09-06 20:41:42.028 -----------------------------------------------
  eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
  java.version=1.8.0_131
  java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
  BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
  Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data file:/E:/EclipsePortable/Data/workspace/

  !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 2 0 2017-09-06 20:41:46.917
  !MESSAGE Can't find Navigator Content Descriptor with id: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.EnhancedJavaRendering

  !ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive 1 0 2017-09-06 20:42:16.644
  !MESSAGE Connected to Drive service at https://www.googleapis.com/

  !ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive 4 0 2017-09-06 20:43:23.266
  !MESSAGE Error reading contents of project from Drive; see Error Log.
  !STACK 0
  java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive.wizards.ScriptProjectImportWizard$2.run(ScriptProjectImportWizard.java:162)
     at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/eclipse/

> The Google Plugin for Eclipse is deprecated and will be removed in January 2018. Migrate to Cloud Tools for Eclipse and/or the GWT Eclipse Plugin as soon as possible to avoid disruption.